# Make fair loss reliable

Tags: system, distributed-computing, distributed, distributed-system, distributed-programming

I'm studying a Distributed System.

I'm following this book "Introduction to Reliable and Secure Distributed Programming" .

In chapter 2, introduce three types of link:

- Fair loss (that I understand is the lighter)
- Stubborn link
- Perfect link.

I saw exercises that ask to make reliable fair loss link during the algorithm creation.

fair loss property say, that according to the book :

> Fair-loss: If a correct process p infinitely often sends a message m
>   to a correct process q, then q delivers m an infinite number of times

So assuming that nobody process crash, why this link is so unreliable?
Maybe the problem is duplication?

So my real question is:

**Can I create, starting from a Fair loss link, a perfect link?**

(Obviously I want to change the fair loss, I don't want to replace it with the perfect link, otherwise, the question would be obvious)

Answer (score 0):

> ***You Asked:*** 'So assuming that nobody process crash, why this link is so unreliable? Maybe the problem is duplication?' ***Answer:*** *Each link that connects two processes in a computer network (or a distributed system) is a special restricted process.* We know that each process can fail; since each link is a kind of process, links can fail as well. Therefore, even every process is correct, the system can be unreliable. ***Conclusion:*** If you want to declare that you have a reliable system, you have to indicate that all the processes and **links** are correct.
>
> ***You Asked:*** 'Can I create, starting from a Fair loss link, a perfect link?' ***Answer:*** Yes, if you read the book that you mentioned, you can find the answer.